# adding data into advancedListView using FluentListView

Tags: c#, frameworks, addition

does anyone here know how to use

```
fluentListView
```

framework? i am trying to create 1 advancedListView but i am having difficulty with adding data

```
AdvancedListView.Items.Add(new object)
AdvancedListView.Items.Add(new object)
AdvancedListView.Items.Add(new object)
```

Comment: Is this related to https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentListView?

Comment: that's right, that's it

Comment: Well, it does not look like it's related to `fluentd`. You might want to edit add `c#` tag in there.

Comment: my bad, so sorry